# Read file accessible only from script in Unix

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I have written a Base shell script that needs password/key which is retrieved from a file.

Base Script---Calls---Key/Password File ---Base Script does further authenticates using the key retrieved

Requirements:

1. No user should be able to get the contents of the file directly
2. Every user should be able to execute Base Script
3. Only the script should be allowed to access the contents of the file

Any other suggestions to use password/key not visible to anyone but configurable in script is welcome

Note: I tried the sudoers approach but still no success

> %usersgroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/key/path

Comment: Point 3 is virtually impossible, AFAIK. You may just want to make a script owned by root and no write access for others, allow usage via `sudo` and store the password in a file readable by root only. Note that it still means having a clear text password file on the system!

Comment: What does the script do? That is, what's the password for? What do you mean with "further authentication", is the script supposed to authenticate the calling user, or authenticate _itself_ to some third system (with the password in the file)? And, in case it matters (probably not if you have `sudo` anyway), which actual system do you run on? Linux? FreeBSD? Something else? It's probably not the actual Unix.

Comment: Please specify "no success" - what error message do you get? Note, that you can't execute a file, which you can't read. If the program access is secured by a password, it should probably be secured by ssh-access and pre shared keys, instead of an easy to lose password. Plain text passwords on the system is an error from the 90ies. They always get lost: Backups, which are readable on a remote machine, thrown away hard drives, which haven't been properly shred, users, reading the RAM of their process, swapfiles, prolonged access to the program to smartphones etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file that has the password, only accessible by root -- chown root, chmod 600.

You should change your script to normally access this file (maybe sourcing the variables there?) and to be owned by root and be only readable/executable by other users, not editable -- chown root, chmod 4755.

Normally, you would enable suid on the script and you would be done, but Linux has disabled suid for scripts. The next step then is to add a sudoers line:

```
%usersgroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/path/to/script
```

And ask users to run the script with sudo.

Comment: I tried this approach and this works but the problem here is I have to make multiple changes where ever the Base Script is being called and also i will lose users env variables within the script as we are running it as root

Comment: @AshishYadav, and if you have other requirements, you may want to edit them into your question...

Comment: @AshishYadav: Well, depending on the usage of the script. You may call "sudo" inside a script, you needen't run the whole script by sudo. But the consequece is, the user has to give his password interactively while running it, which might not be an option. DISCLAIMER: I'm not a security expert in Linux or elsewhere.

Comment: @AshishYadav, your extra comment does not provide any insight. Please correct some obvious error in your initial post and add the needed information. 1) I suppose that by "Base" you mean "bash", right? 2) Adding a file that you want to read (and not execute) in sudoers achieves nothing.3) What do you mean by changes? 5) Have you seen the -E sudo option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this would work, but in theory it would! You could `chmod 700 /path/to/key` and, to make sure that nobody except the bash script could read it, have an encrypted version of the password in /path/to/key and have the script do the decryption and then check the password. Of course, you'd need to disable read access for non-root users in the script to stop them from just cracking the code and editing it to have the script work directly, so make sure to `chmod 744 /path/to/script`. However, a savvy user with root  access could just use `chmod` and revert all our hard work. So, we'd need to instead have the script call some machine code to do the decryption, and then we'd realize we just spent a weekend reinventing DRM. I hope this answers your question. For your information, I'm against DRM (as per the EFF and Defective By Design), but I think it'd be fun reinventing it.